Where is winget?
Where is winget? Is it some kind of built-in command, cause I can't find it in my path
> winget -v
v1.8.1911

> where winget

Returns nothing.
If I search for the file, I get some weird .pf (prefetch) file.
Get-ChildItem -Path c:\ -Recurse -Filter "*winget.exe*" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue|Convert-Path|format-table -Wrap *
C:\Windows\prefetch\WINGET.EXE-36614303.pf

Any pointers as to where it is?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/package-manager/winget/

Winget is a Microsoft Store "app", and installed in C:\Users<user-name>\AppData\Local\Packages. The question is, why do you need the executable's location? One cannot make a functional shortcut directly to it.

where winget doesn't call the "where" program, it calls PowerShell's Where-Object.

PS C:\> where.exe winget
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\winget.exe

The folder contains MS Store "Execution Aliases" which are links (a subtype of reparse point) to Appx/Msix package contents.
